# Azure DevOps - Run Build job Conditional statement and expression

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to run a CI stage in Azure DevOps in a self-hosted Linux Agent. The stages look like below:

CI - Build Job:

- Task 1: Python script to check a TRUE OR FALSE condition
- Task 2: Bash script to execute certain commands

Now, Task 2 Should run only when the Task 1 py script execution contains only "TRUE".

I have referred a few docs which suggested to go with custom conditions from the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

But not sure how to write custom condition as I am new to this.

**NOTE: I want to try only in a custom mode, not in YAML**

Comment: what is custom mode?

Comment: My apologies., its classic mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can define a new variable or update a variable in the python script when the Task 1 py script execution contains only "TRUE", then use the variable in the condition. Sample condition `eq(variables['{variable name}'], '{variable value}')`, the task 2 will only run if the condition is determined to be successful, if the result is fail, the task 2 will be skipped.